# mexFunction: conflicting values between Internal and Output doubles

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have a matlab code and I am trying to rewrite part of it in C using the mexFunction in order to get time performance. My "mexfunction" output is as 2 dimensional matrix array of doubles. My code is the following:

```
//...

#include "matrix.h"
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

// ...

size_t NumberRows=...;
size_t NumberColumns=...;

double *MatrixOutput;
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(NumberRows,NumberColumns,mxREAL);
MatrixOutput  = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

// ...

for(int m=0; m<NumberRows; m++){

    for(int n=0; n<NumberColumns; n++){

       // BODY PROGRAM (getting re[n])

       MatrixOutput[m*ncols+n] = re[n];

    }

}
return;
}
```

My problem is that if I save the values of re[] into a file, I get different values than the ones saved into MatrixOutput.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

David

Comment: How are the values different in the file? Can you give an example of the two sets of values? Thanks!

Comment: Please define "save the values of re[] into a file." How exactly are you saving them?

Comment: Hey! The problem is now fixed. MexFunction stores the matrix data into a vector and I was missunderstanding the way in which does this. It does it column by column and not row by row, as I was thinking. This is why I was getting weird results without having segmentation errors. T